# Reason to pass data using struct inode and struct file in Linux device driver programming

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, inode

I'm studying Chapter 3.5 of [Linux Device Drivers, 3rd edition](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-5). This section introduces a method to retrieve a custom structure we defined ourselves from `struct inode *inode` in the open function:

```
int scull_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    struct scull_dev *dev;

    dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_dev, cdev);
    filp->private_data = dev; /* for other methods */

    }
    return 0;          
}
```

From my understanding, while the device is opened, the `struct inode *inode` representing the device is passed to `scull_open`. Then, the custom structure `dev` is extracted and passed to `filp->private_data` so that other methods such as `scull_read` can use it:

```
ssize_t scull_read(struct file *filp, char _ _user *buf, size_t count,
                loff_t *f_pos)
{
    struct scull_dev *dev = filp->private_data; 
    /* other codes that uses *dev   */
}
```

This seems fine to me until I realized that we already had a `struct scull_dev *dev` during initialization in `scull_setup_cdev` [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-4).

I'm rather confused since I thought we can make `struct scull_dev *dev` a global variable, then `scull_read` and other methods will eventually have access to it without going through all the passing using `inode` and `file`.

My question is, why don't we just make it a global variable?

Can anyone provide some practical examples of using this method to pass data ?

Comment: Let this question/answer be a lesson to you in why global variables are bad and should never be used except when there's no other way.

Comment: Yeah but while teaching the writer must tell why and what is the use of the particular function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thread-safety! What if two threads/processes are using the driver simultaneously?

Comment: Even threads in different single-threaded processes. (Which most people would naively just call "processes" rather than "threads".)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having some doubts. Let's say I have a simple user program (let's call it `open_device.c`) to communicate with my driver through system calls like `open()`, `read()`,`write()`, etc. If I'm very sure that at a single time, I will only use **one** `open_device.c` to access my driver, do I still need to take care of the thread safety concern ? Does the thread safety issue happen only when I'm using **two** or **more** `open_device.c` to access my driver?

Comment: What is the lifetime of the struct, does it persist between system calls? If it does, your program will break if you open a second file before you close the first.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to why you think this makes it thread-safe? I can't see any extra protection it would give. All threads would point to the same scull_dev structure, effectively making it a global variable.

Answer (score 10):

The main reason is so that your driver can manage more than one device. For example, you can create (`mknod`) several devices `/dev/scull1`, `/dev/scull2`, `/dev/scull3`... and then each of these will have a different `scull_dev` associated with it.

With a global variable you are limited to one. And even if your driver only supports one such device, there is little reason not to design the code future proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid using the private data to store your actual device, which is a common choice if you need private data for something different. In that case you will need to retrieve the minor number in the scull_read routine. It will be something like that:

```
ssize_t scull_read( struct file *filp,
                     char __user* buf,
                     size_t count,
                    loff_t * f_pos ) {

    int minor = MINOR(filp->f_dentry->d_inode->i_rdev);
    printk( "reading on minor number %d\n", minor);
    /* use dev[minor] in ur code */
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I donot think it is a thead-safety issue. It is more like a design choice. If I am not mistaken, thread-safety is achieved by down and up the semaphore in scull_dev. If you dig into the code, you can see open, read, write all used down_interruptible().

I guess the author 1) believes accessing scull_dev directly doesnot look good 2) wants to show us how to use private_data. By putting the point to scull_dev in struct file whose pointer is sent to each operation, each operation can access it without using global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The scull driver is implemented with 4 minors, each of which has a separate scull_dev, each scull_dev has "struct cdev" embedded in it. Now Let's say User has opened scull0 from /dev/scull0. In the open() function you need to point to the correct scull_dev structure. The scull_dev structures are dynamically allocated.

You can see the full implementation here
https://github.com/mharsch/ldd3-samples/blob/master/scull/main.c#L450